# Retrieving multiple values from Map

Tags: haskell

Suppose I have a list of keys and a Map. What is the easiest way to iterate over the list to retrieve the values in the Map that correspond to these keys and create another list of them?

```
retrieveMultipleValues myMap myKeys = 
  map (\x -> lookup x myMap) myKeys -- ???
```

In this case:

```
myMap :: Map String String
myKeys :: [String]
```

My gut tells there must be a monadic way to do this.

Comment: What's the problem with your definition of `retrieveMultipleValues`? That should do the trick, and give you a list of `Maybe String`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `lookup` and `mapMaybe`:

```
import Data.Maybe

retrieveMultipleValues m = mapMaybe (\k -> Map.lookup k m)
```

Comment: but how do I return a pure list, not a list of Maybe's?

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp - It returns a list of values with keys present in the map.

Comment: one more thing. how do I make sure that the return values from `retrieveMultipleValues` are in the same order as the keys in `myKeys`? If the length of the result `retrieveMultipleValues` == length of `keys` then they are in the same order, correct?

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp - The documentation of `mapMaybe` suggests that it should preserve the order, and the current implementation does.